# Deep Copy of string using new Operator over loading

Tags: c++

i am just trying to perform deepcopy of string, but issue is while displaying the string copied to another pointer is not getting displayed .

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<cstring>
  using namespace std;


 void *operator new(size_t size)
 {
   void *ptr = malloc(size);
    cout << "\n\ninside new operator" << endl;
   return ptr;
 }

 void operator delete(void *ptr)
 {
   free(ptr);
   cout << "\n\ninside delete operator" << endl;
 }


 int main()
{
   char *str = "hello world";
   char *shallowCopy = str;
   char *deepcopy = new char[(strlen(str) + 1)];

   while (*str != '\0')
  {
    *deepcopy = *str;
    deepcopy++;
    str++;

   }
*deepcopy = '\0';
cout << "\n\n shallow string is :-" << shallowCopy << endl;
cout << "\n\n deep string is :-" << deepcopy << endl;

  delete str;
  delete shallowCopy;
  delete deepcopy;
getchar();

}
```

i don't what went wrong in this code , can someone help me out in fixing this.

Comment: Do note that `char *str = "hello world";` should not compile.  `"hello world"` is a `const char[N]` and using a non const pointer to it violates const correctness.

Comment: The problem is not using `std::string`.

Comment: Correct answer below: can I downvote the question now please?

Comment: Use `std::strcpy` to copy the text, That's its job.

Comment: @PeteBecker i don't want to use any built in function to perform copying of strings

Comment: @user5794230 Not only using `new` in c++ is probably worst practice you can have, overloading the `new` operator (which won't have any effect there at all) seems to be even worse. Use a `std::string` to manage these things properly. There's a rare chance you'll be really smarter than the c++ standard commitee is.

Comment: If you don't want to use any built-in functions then you shouldn't be using `malloc` and `free`. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker: Or cout. In fact, really you should bin the compiler and use a hex keypad to enter in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main function should be like the following,

```
int main()
{
   char *str = "hello world";
   char *shallowCopy = str;
   char *deepcopy = new char[(strlen(str) + 1)];

   while (*str != '\0')
   {
     *deepcopy = *str;
      deepcopy++;
      str++;
   }
  *deepcopy = '\0';
  cout << "\n\n shallow string is :-" << shallowCopy << endl;
  cout << "\n\n deep string is :-" << deepcopy - strlen(shallowCopy) << endl;  /* here*/
}
```

The reason is that after the `while` loop, the pointers, `str` and `deepcopy` are pointed to the end of the string. Note that the line `*deepcopy = '\0';`  will make pointer deepcopy point to a NULL character, or, the C-string termination character.

Then you also need to remember to call delete.

Comment: `deepcopy - strlen(shallowcopy)` gives me the heebie-jeebies, but it's not incorrect.

Comment: yes, it is kind of dirty but my guess is that the author just wants to practice C++, not for production.

Comment: yes , i am just trying to copy one string to another by performing new operator overloading..

Comment: the overloading part is fine. But your pointer now no longer points to the beginnin of the copied string (because you moved it by ++)

Comment: yes.. thanks i got it...

Answer (score 0):

(By the way, you need to overload the `new` operator with brackets).

You need to set `deepcopy` back to the start of the string: at the `cout` it points to the NUL terminator.

You'll need that original pointer anyway, in order to perform an adequate call to `delete[]`.

Note that your recent edit has introduced a truck load of *undefined behaviour* into your program. You need to call `delete[]` solely on the pointer you got back from your call to `new[]`.

Comment: can you please explain "deepcopy back to the start of the string: at the cout it points to the NUL terminator."  by providing some sample code.. it will be a great help

Comment: Well, what do you think `deepcopy++` does?!

Comment: its moving to next element address or similar to *deepcopy++ = *str++

Comment: Yes indeed but how are you going to print out the string if you haven't retained the original value of `deepcopy`? That is the problem you have here.

Comment: yes.. printing of string is the  issue , i am seeing that after each iteration values are getting assigned

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should use C++ headers like

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
```

instead of

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. So it would be correctly to write using the qualifier `const`

const char *str = "hello world";
   const char *shallowCopy = str;

You may not call the operator delete to free memory that was not allocated with operator new. So these statements

```
delete str;
delete shallowCopy;
```

result in undefined behavior of the program.

In this loop

```
while (*str != '\0')
{
    *deepcopy = *str;
    deepcopy++;
    str++;

}
```

there are changed the original values of the pointers `str` and `deepcopy`. So again this statement

```
delete deepcopy;
```

results in undefined behavior of the program.

To copy one string to another you should use additional pointers or an index variable., For example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; ( deepcopy[i] = str[i] ) != '\0'; i++ ) 
{
    // empty body
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for line by line explanation...it really helped